# how to import specific tags from RSS XML into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, import, simplexml

What I'm trying to do is to import a RSS XML feed into a MySQL database using PHPs simpleXML function. But the only thing the PHP script does is writing 0's to my database. What am I doin' wrong?

Sample rss.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="/divers/rss/xslt.php" ?> 
<rss version="2.0"  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
       <title></title>
       <link></link>
       <description></description>
   <lastBuildDate></lastBuildDate>
   <ttl></ttl>
   <item>
       <title></title>
       <description></description>
       <link></link>
       <guid></guid>
       <pubDate></pubDate>
   </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

PHP

```
<?php

  include ('config.php'); 

  $xml_file = "http://xml.xml/rss.xml";
  $xml_load = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xml_file));

  $link = (string)$xml_load->link;
  $guid = (string)$xml_load->guid;

  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (link,guid) VALUES('$link','$guid');";

  mysql_query($sql) or die("Error ".mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was doing:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL); // loads in simple xml format

        foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
            $title = stripslashes($entry->title);
            $summary = stripslashes($entry->summary);
        }
```

As you can see I use `stripsplashes()`.

I guess it would look like:

```
foreach($xml->item as $item) {
  $link = stripslashes($item->link);
  $guid = stripslashes($item->guid);
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: link in script.php on line 13
Notice: Undefined variable: guid in script.php on line 13. Something is wrong.

Comment: Did you refer to channel first? Like $xml = $loaded_string->chanel? It's like going down on hierarchy. Go through all steps and you will be there. channel->item->link/description.

Comment: Did that now, blank page, again 2 zeros into db.

Comment: Do you use the same text of xml as it is shown upthere in this post? Because if it is empty than it's fine about blank page.
Also I found this tutorial, may be it will help:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Comment: Yeah, but the output is a zero in every column.